# Datatables - Server-side processing - DB column merging

Tags: php, mysql, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm currently using DataTables 1.10.5 server-side processing feature: http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Haven't done any major modifications yet, just inserted the column names, etc.

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'clinicaId', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'rotaId',  'dt' => 1 ),
array(
    'db'        => 'delegadoId',
    'dt'        => 2,
    'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
        $delegado = new Delegado($d);
        return $delegado->display('name');
    }
));
```

So, in my sql table, I have 2 columns called **cp4** (format: 0000), and **cp3** (format: 000) that are part of a postal code.

I want to merge those columns into one, when displaying on a datatable (format: 0000-000). This could be solved quickly, by rewriting my SQL tables. But that would defeat the purpose of having them separated, so I can get the specific location it refers to without having to explode the results.

I haven't found anything specific for my struggle. Already wasted about 2 hours on this, any enlightenment will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating them:

```
array( 'db' => '`field1`.`field2`', 'dt' => 'concatenated_fields' ),
```

Comment: I opted to create my own script for server-side processing as I had way more control on filtering and without having to include a complex class. Will try this, as soon as the opportunity arises.

Comment: @bpeterson76 I also want to merge 2 columns and tried the same concatenation but it's not working, giving error.