# datatables format column from multiple sources?(Server side processing)

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

Im trying to get server side processing working with concatenated columns.

I came across this this post: [Datatables - Server-side processing - DB column merging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29147633/datatables-server-side-processing-db-column-merging)

But when I use that format I get SQL errors. But I also want to insert say... a space between the fields... is this possible?

**Edit:**

**Example:**

Table init:

```
var customer_Table = $('#customer_Table').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "php/server_processing.php",
    stateSave: true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
    'order': 2, 'asc' ]],
    "columns": [{"title":"id","visible":false,"type":"html-string"},{"title":"name","visible":true,"type":"html-string"},[{"title":"address","visible":true,"type":"html-string"}
} );
```

Column scheme:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => "id" ),
    array( 'db' => 'name',  'dt' => "Name" ),
    array( 'db' => "`street` . ' ' . `city` . '<br>' . `postal` . ' ' . `country`" 'dt' => "address"
    )
);
```

Error:

```
{"error":"An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`id`,`name`, `JCP`, ``street` . ' ' . `city` . '<br>' . `postal` . ' ' . `country``...' at line 1"}
```

Comment: please post: code, db schema, db sample, errors. with out this basic information your questions is unanswerable.

Comment: better? its not my direct code since my code has many many columns that would just make the post harder to understand.

Comment: better, but im not reading the whole datatables documentation to work out what it requires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the error message, the processing engine is expecting a valid column reference for 'db'. Each 'db' should refer to a valid column reference in the WHERE clause, and each 'dt' contains the label to be displayed for that column.

Your reference is, according to your snippet:

```
"`street` . ' ' . `city` . '<br>' . `postal` . ' ' . `country`"
```

Which doesn't mean much to most database engines I am familiar with. Try something like this:

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => "id" ),
    array( 'db' => 'name',  'dt' => "Name" ),
    array( 'db' => "CONCAT(`street`, ' ', `city`, '<br>', `postal`, ' ', `country`)", 
            'dt' => "address")
);
```

Comment: is there any way to stop the SSP.class from adding `` around the concat statement? or do I have to add some logic to prevent it?

Comment: after adding some code to make sure the sql returns correctly the data tables just returns:DataTables warning: table id=customer_Table - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. .... for some reason it tried to load the 2000 records at once aswell

Comment: when looking at the data it is returning correctly but has decided to return all records?

Comment: Sorry, not that familiar with the framework you're using. It seems like the 'db' parameter in this instance needs to hold a reference to a single column in the table. You'll need to check the documentation on this framework to figure out how to do it properly. Closest I got in a 30 second search is this:
http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

Comment: so, after further investigation I've found that get request that data tables is sending contains a length column ordering and such but in the php it can't see most of the get variables...

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => "id" ),
    array( 'db' => 'name',  'dt' => "Name" ),
    array( 'db' => "CONCAT(`street`, ' ', `city`, '<br>', `postal`, ' ', `country`)", 
            'as' => "address",
            'dt' => "address")
);
```